# React Native:How to detect function component will unmount?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

My RN 0.62.2 app needs to automatically save page data just before the function component unmounts. The idea is that when the user close the page (detecting losing focus may not work here since user may zoom in image in modal screen), then the save (to backend server) is automatically triggered.  Since it is function component, how to know when the component will unmount?

Here is the sample code of a function component shall do:

```
    const MyCom = () => {
    
      //do something here. ex, open gallery to upload image, zoon in image in `modal screen,  enter input`
    
      if (component will unmount) {
        //save the data by sending them to backend server
      }
    }
```

The `useEffect` triggers with every rendering and will have performance issue if keep saving to backend server with each and every rendering. The auto save only happens once just before the component unmount. User may click `Back` or `Home` button to leave the page.

Comment: return of `useEffect ` with an empty array `[]` as a dependency will be trigger only once when the component is unmounted.

Comment: `Tony Nguyen`, did you mean cleanup function in `useEffect` with 2nd variable [] will trigger once the component is unmounted? I understand that [] execute `useEffect` only once after initial rendering.

Comment: Yes. But it still depends on what you have in your "saving data" function if that function using a state React still recommend you to have that state in dependencies. In that case you might want to use `useReducer`  instead of using `useState`. Please provide your saving data function detail to get better help.

Comment: The saving is to send form data back to remote backend server for update. Those form data are all defined by `useState` and has 10 fields. Also there is an array state `fieldUpdatedList` which is to track all the fields which has been changed. `fieldUpdatedList` is empty when the component is rendered initially. However if `fieldUpdatedList` is not empty when component is unmounted, then this state and all related field states will be sent to backend server all at once for update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yoı must use useEffect for componentWillUnmount in functional components.

```
const MyCom = () => {

  //do something here. ex, open gallery to upload image, zoon in image in 

  useEffect(() => {
    // Component Did Mount

    return () => {
      // ComponentWillUnmount
    }
  },[])

  return(/*Component*/)
}
```

Comment: I think should have been `return () => {`